# Mac Lane CTFWM, Explanation about Yoneda functor

Tags: category-theory

Page 61, below an addendum Yoneda Lemma, at the bottom of the page, last sentence:

The object function $r\mapsto D(r,-)$ and the arrow function $$(f:s\rightarrow r)\mapsto D(f,-):D(r,-)\rightarrow D(s,-)$$ for f an arrow of $D$ together define a full and faithful functor.

I tried to prove first that this is really functor. If we name this functor $Y$, we have to prove that $Y_{1_r}=1_{Y_r}$ and this is quite easy, but I have some problems with proving $Y_{g\circ f}= Y_g \circ Y_f$. 
If I understand well and if $f:A\rightarrow B, g:B\rightarrow C$ and T is one object from $D$, left side is following:
$(Y_{g\circ f})_T(h:C \rightarrow T)=h\circ (g \circ f)$
How to prove that left side is the same. I have confusion because $Y_g:D(C,-)\rightarrow D(B,-)$ and $Y_f:(D(B,-)\rightarrow D(A,-)$, so $(Y_g)_T:Y_C(T) \rightarrow Y_B(T)$ and $(Y_f)_T:Y_B(T) \rightarrow Y_A(T)$. Hence I can't compose right side, i.e. $((Y_g)_T \circ (Y_f)_T)(h:C\rightarrow T)$ is not well defined.

Where are my mistakes?

Comment: It says that this is a functor $D^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}^D$, not $D \to \mathbf{Set}^D$. So you should be proving $Y_{g\circ f} = Y_f \circ Y_g$, not $Y_{g \circ f} = Y_g \circ Y_f$, unless you are letting $\circ$ mean composition in $D^{\operatorname{op}}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for answering. Composition at the left side is of course in $D^{Op}$. I understood that then $f' : B \rightarrow A, g': C \rightarrow B$ are arrows in $D$ and also $f' \circ g'$. If I should prove $Y_{g \circ f}=Y_f \circ Y_g$, evrything is clear, but I was confused with this rotation and supposed that maybe I had to use composition $Y_g' \circ Y_f'$, which is well defined but its domain isn't morphisms from $C$ to $T$. This was very confusing to me.